# Converting a textbox's text into a string to be used as a byte

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, byte

OK so I would like to have a few textboxes on my c# form and then when a certain button is clicked it will take the text in each textbox and turn it into a byte to be written into a file.
I know how to do everything but take the textboxes' text and turn it into a byte. can anyone help?
And the textboxes text will already be in hex form so it shouldnt have to be converted.

Comment: What do you mean by "turn it into a byte"? A byte can only hold a numeric value from 0-255, whereas a textbox contains a string of arbitrary length. If you want to write a textbox's text to a file you don't need to perform any data-type conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given textbox:

```
byte data = byte.Parse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

The second parameter allows the hex format to parse. Of course; if the given value is too large; you'll have some problems (it will throw). You can always use `TryParse` instead.

MSDN for byte.TryParse: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4eszwye3(v=vs.110).aspx))

MSDN for the NumberStyles enum: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: OK that kinda works, but I cant write the bytes stored for some reason.

Comment: @JoeOliveira That sounds like a different problem :) You may have another question (make sure to do your research first! If you can get to 20 rep; you could also ask in chat.

Comment: @bardleydotnet ive done research but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: Ok; but I can't solve a problem in the blind. If you are having trouble writing your bytes out; ask a new question (feel free to link to this one if it provides context).

Answer (score 0):

You can write the bytes as ones and zeros to a text file.

The example below assumes you have a textbox named textbox1, a button click event named buttonRecord_Click, and you have included a reference to the System.IO namespace at the top of your code (using System.IO;). Replace "PathOfYourTextFile.txt" with the actual path.

```
private void buttonRecordBytes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Break if textbox1 is empty.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
            return;

        // Variables:
        int charCount = textbox1.Text.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[charCount];
        string[] byteStrings = new string[charCount];

        // StreamWriter will write the bytes to the text file.
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("PathOfYourTextFile.txt", true);

        // Record each character byte in textfile.
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in textbox1.Text)
        {
            // ASCII:
            try
            {
                bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(c);
                byteStrings[i] = Convert.ToString(bytes[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
            }
            // UTF8:
            catch
            {
                bytes[i] = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.ToString().ToCharArray())[i];
                byteStrings[i] = Convert.ToString(bytes[i], 2).PadLeft(24, '0');
            }

            // Append character and bit info to textfile.
            sw.WriteLine("Character \"" + c.ToString() + "\" bits as ones and zeros: " +
                byteStrings[i]);

            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(c.ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(byteStrings[i]);
            listviewBytes.Items.Add(lvi);

            i++;
        }
    sw.Close();
    }
```